# Does VMWare Workstation create virtual network adapters other than vmnet1 and vmnet8?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, virtual-network

I noticed with VMWare Workstation the default virtual network adapters on the host are VMNet1 and VMNet8 (Host Only and NAT).  If I add additional virtual networks, they do not appear in the Network Connections section on the host.  This is potentially problematic if I wanted to be able to modify these on the host (ie: static IP assignment).

Is there any way to have the additional adapters show up or are networks 1 and 8 the only ones exposed to the host via Network Connections?

Edit: The Host OS is Win7 Pro 64 bit

Comment: I assume you're talking about a Windows host?  You did click OK/Apply in the VMware Virtual Network Editor to finish adding the new VMnet, right?  It works for me; when I add a new VMnet and click OK, it adds a host adapter that shows up under Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections.

Comment: Yes, this is a Win7 host.

Answer (score 0):

By default it should.  When you created the additional networks (in the Virtual Network Editor), do you have the box "Connect a host virtual adapter to this network" checked?  If this box is unchecked there will not be a virtual adapter for your host.

Comment: I do not see this option in the Virtual Network Editor.
I do see this option when I choose to set up the NIC in the Guest VM settings for a Bridged connection.  But this option does not appear to be available in the Virtual Network Editor.

On the Guest VM, I am not using the bridged option, I am using Custom: Specific Network for 2 adapter on VMnet0 and VMnet2.  One of these is bridged but when I use Custom, there is no option to replicate the physical network.

Comment: what version of Workstation are you using?

Comment: VMware Workstation 14